# Receiving Error: xhr poll error socket.io client React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am receiving an `Error: xhr poll error` in the connect_error event when trying to connect to my websocket gateway.
I am using `"socket.io-client": "^4.2.0"`.

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3001";

const socket = io(ENDPOINT);

socket.on("connect_error", (e: any) => {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: New versions of socket.io requires also cors on server side. https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try to set up the client connection to use only websocket transport. By default it is using weboscket and polling.

```js
{
   transports: ['websocket']
}
```

So your code will become:

```js
const socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
   transports: ['websocket']
});
```

Answer (score 2):

set `server.listen` instead of

```
 app.listen
```